# CAT6A home wiring - 100mbps over series-connected runs - gigabit over standalone runs

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, home-networking, cable

Was hoping to avoid one posting another "100mbps over CAT6A" posts but here we are! Apologies for the length.

I'm currently running ethernet cables in a 1900s house (UK) as the walls and ceilings make WiFi lose 90% in the room directly above the hub, so running cables while floors etc. are up. I'm using:

- CAT6A S/FTP solid core indoor cable as price and availability made it the best option - although I'm aware this complicates things a bit with shielding
- Keystone RJ45 CAT6A shielded sockets for each room
- CAT6A S/FTP patch cables
- 2 laptops with gigabit ports for testing
- A Virgin router with 2.5gbps port
- A split-unit RJ45 sequencer tester

Current setup is:

- Living room where router is - 2 sockets in 1 panel
- Downstairs office where rack etc. will be - 4 sockets in 2 panels
- Upstairs temporary office while renovating - 2 sockets in 1 panel
- 2 cables for each room, running in conduit

Both the living room and upstairs office run to the downstairs office. In the near future I'll likely put a Ubiquiti Dream Machine etc. or something similar with patch panel and switch there and use one of the living room ports for WAN from router to UDM and the rest as LAN from the UDM:

**Router - patch - socket - cable - socket - patch - UDM (etc.) - patch - socket - cable - socket - patch - PC**

My problem is while I renovate etc. I'm trying to just get a direct connection from the living room router to upstairs office for PCs as I'm not ready to buy the full network setup yet and don't want to do a dedicated run from upstairs office to living room, so planned on (unconventionally) jumping the downstairs office sockets together (living room <-> upstairs office) via patch cables to get gigabit there straight from the router. However, when I do that, I'm only getting 100mbps links (100BaseTX Full Duplex according to ifconfig).

**Router - patch - socket - cable - socket - patch - socket - cable - socket - patch - PC**

Things I've checked:

- Each keystone jack has been checked and reterminated correctly
- Tested every combination of cables together with no joy
- Every cable run tested individually and getting gigabit (1000BaseT Full Duplex) no problem (router/PC - patch - socket - cable - socket - patch - PC/router)
- RJ45 sequencer verifies each wire is connected properly including ground. Tested individually on each cable run and from end-to-end living room to upstairs with patch cables as intended - no problems
- Each termination is T568b
- Cable lengths are well within CAT6A spec
- No major runs past AC power cables or any interfering/noise producing equipment

To me the most obvious thing to me is a crossover somewhere with socket - patch cable - socket setup killing it but as far as I can tell modern NICs have made crossover cables obsolete and should deal with it. I am using a fairly old MSI laptop (2015) and a MacBook with a pretty old dock (2015ish) for testing so wondering if Auto-MDIX isn't working but seems very unlikely? Also the sockets aren't properly grounded as the router won't be grounding them nor the laptop on the other side (patch panel etc. will sort this properly eventually), but I did temporarily ground them in the downstairs office (wiring from keystone/drain wire to earth point) with no luck.

Any ideas? Hoping it's something simple but the fact I'm getting gigabit over individual runs makes finding the fault difficult! I'm going to try some more electrical (resistance etc.) tests tomorrow but any other ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: to be clear, you've tested every `socket` (I take it these are double sided sockets?)

Comment: Yes, dual keystone wall sockets, terminated to the cables, which terminates to the same type of sockets on the other side. Each cable tested individually and getting gigabit

Comment: Only thing I can think of is cable length. Note: while 100meters should manage gigabit, you have 4 sockets (i.e. 8 extra connections compared to a straight device to device run) in that temporary solution, which could significantly reduce the cable length limit

Comment: a thought ... what if you replace `- socket - patch - socket -` with `- socket - patch - switch - patch - socket -`

Comment: I'm with @JaromandaX - I'd try dropping a small budget switch into one of those patch>patch connections. Tenner on eBay, don't need anything fancy…. 'cept it's Easter & nothing will turn up til at least Tuesday :\ [Curry's have got a TP-Link for 11 quid; they'll be open today & Sat.]

Comment: @JaromandaX I went and bought a £60 TP Link managed 8 port switch (with 4 PoE ports!) and it now works fine, 990Mbit internet speed to upstairs office through the downstairs office switch from living room router! Can only thing it’s a crossover thing when just using a patch in place of the switch and the computers or router can’t handle it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm doubtful `it’s a crossover thing`, more likely the attenuation thing I mentioned